# Change popup text in Kivy

Tags: python, popup, kivy

I am new to Kivy so this may be a trivial question. I am working on a project that has two screens, each of which contains a button that generates a popup. I would like for the popup to display a statement containing the name of the current screen. My problem is despite having a method to change the popup text, the placeholder text is always being displayed. Why doesn't the changeText method change the text of the popup?

My problem seems similar to the one shown:

- [Kivy Label.text Property doesn't update on the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305280/kivy-label-text-property-doesnt-update-on-the-ui)

However I am having some trouble understanding how to apply it to my specific situation.

Python Code:

```
class Screen1(Screen):  
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass 

class MyManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class PopUp(Popup):
    def changeText(self,nameStr):
        self.ids.label.text = "You are on Screen %s!" %nameStr #this is text that I want to display 

class PrimaryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyManager()

PrimaryApp().run()
```

Kv Code:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<MyManager>:
    Screen1:
        id: screen1
    Screen2: 
        id: screen2

<Screen1>:
    name: "one"
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        rows: 2
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Go to Screen Two"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "two" 
        Button: 
            id: button2
            text: "Display Popup" 
            on_release: 
                Factory.PopUp().changeText(root.name)
                Factory.PopUp().open()
<Screen2>: 
    name: "two" 
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        rows: 2 
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Go to Screen One" 
            on_release: root.manager.current = "one" 
        Button: 
            id: button2
            text: "Display Popup"
            on_release:
                Factory.PopUp().changeText(root.name)
                Factory.PopUp().open()


<PopUp>:
    id:pop
    size_hint: (.5,.5)
    title: "Notice!" 
    Label: 
        id: label
        text: "PLACEHOLDER TEXT" #this is not the code I want displayed
```

[1]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everytime you call `Factory().Popup()` it creates a brand new `Popup` which has nothing to do with the previous. What you can do it's:

in the kv:

```
...
<Screen1>:
    name: "one"
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        rows: 2
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Go to Screen Two"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "two"
        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Display Popup"
            on_release:
                p = Factory.PopUp()
                p.changeText(root.name)
                p.open()
```

And the same thing for the second screen. But everytime you release these buttons it creates a new created popup too much memory wasted. The best thing you can do it is initialize your screen manager with a popup and then only change the text of this popup:

Python:

```
...
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

...
class PopUp(Popup):
    def changeText(self,*args):
        self.ids.label.text = "You are on Screen %s!" % args[0].current

class MyManager(ScreenManager):
    popup = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.popup = PopUp()
        self.bind(current=self.popup.changeText)
```

and the kv:

```
...
<PopUp>:
    id:pop
    size_hint: (.5,.5)
    title: "Notice!"
    Label:
        id: label
        text: "You are on Screen one!"

<Screen1>:
    name: "one"
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        rows: 2
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Go to Screen Two"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "two"
        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Display Popup"
            on_release:
                root.manager.popup.open() #Same thing for the second screen
```

Comment: I have a couple of follow-up questions: 1) What is the function of args[0].current? 2) What is the function of self.bind(current=self.popup.changeText)?

Comment: args[0] is your screen manager so args[0].current is the name of the current screen. the bind function "bind" the changeText method to the screen manager current property so everytime the current screen change, the changeText is automatically called

Answer (score 1):

Use Popup event, *on_open* to change the Popup content, Label widget's text.

[Popup » API](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.popup.html)

> Events: on_open:
>                Fired
>   when the Popup is opened.

## Snippets

```
<PopUp>:
    on_open:
        label.text = "You are on Screen %s!" % app.root.current
    id:pop
    ...
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class MyManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class PopUp(Popup):
    pass


class PrimaryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyManager()


PrimaryApp().run()
```

### primary.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyManager>:
    Screen1:
        id: screen1
    Screen2:
        id: screen2

<Screen1>:
    name: "one"
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        rows: 2
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Go to Screen Two"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "two"
        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Display Popup"
            on_release:
                Factory.PopUp().open()
<Screen2>:
    name: "two"
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        rows: 2
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Go to Screen One"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "one"
        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Display Popup"
            on_release:
                Factory.PopUp().open()


<PopUp>:
    on_open:
        label.text = "You are on Screen %s!" % app.root.current
    id:pop
    size_hint: (.5,.5)
    title: "Notice!"
    Label:
        id: label
        text: "PLACEHOLDER TEXT" #this is not the code I want displayed
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Popup at Screen 1]
[image: Img02 - Popup at Screen 2]